# SQL Intersect only if some values given for the parameter (Conditional Intersect)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've query to intersect three queries based on three parameters being given.

So Ive done it using simple intersect as something like this

```
Select name, email from table1 where param='p1'
intersect
Select name, email from table1 where param='p2'
intersect
Select name, email from table1 where param='p3'
```

But the problem is sometimes few of the parameters having no data or blank. in that case the query results nothing because of intersect with blank data. So how can I handle this situation, so that if no data for one parameter (Among any of the 3), that query should not be considered in the whole

Comment: even if you default values for non-existent data `intersect` wouldn't give you a result, unless all the 3 parameters are missing and you use the same default values for all of them.

Comment: There's no need to explain it to me again like I'm five. I understood what you were saying and clearly stated that I was talking about different rows, not the same row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `INTERSECT` on the same column three times? `INTERSECT` is essentially an `INNER JOIN`. As already noted, INNER JOINS according to the VENN diagram only return result sets that are found in each successive query (meaning {A}U{B} is NOT the same as {A}U{C} )

Actually, your question does not answer whether the param is a `@variable`, in which case for index reasons you should use transfer the parameter to a variable before passing it into the query. *Otherwise, the query will not be using a SARG*

Instead, use the following:

```
DECLARE @Param  [DATA_TYPE]{#}
      , @Param2 [DATA_TYPE]{#}
      , @Param3 [DATA_TYPE]{#}

SET @Param = [USP_Proc @param = 'p1']
  , @Param2 = [USP_Proc @param = 'p2']
  , @Param3 = [USP_Proc @param = 'p3']

SELECT  NAME
      , EMAIL
 FROM table1
 WHERE col_1 = @param
    OR col_1 = @param2
    OR col_1 = @param3
```

Answer (score 0):

Intersect only returns values if the values in query A also exist in query B and they also exist in query C

So in the first example the value 'A' exists in all three queries so it will return 'A'.  In the second example, as you are intersecting three queries and 'A' does not exist in all three queries so it return no values.  You may want to use "Union" instead of "Intersect" as it returns data when the values exist in query A or B or C as shown in the third example which would return values of both 'A' and 'B'.

```
Example 1:

SELECT 'A'
intersect
SELECT 'A'
intersect
SELECT 'A'

Example 2:

SELECT 'A'
intersect
SELECT 'A'
intersect
SELECT 'B'

Example 3:

SELECT 'A'
UNION
SELECT 'A'
UNION
SELECT 'B'
```